# Codeigniter How to populate mult icheckbox from database

Tags: codeigniter, checkbox

```html
<tr>
                                     <td>Role1</td><td>
<div class="Oinput" id="Ocheckbox">
<span class="rcs_input_label"></span>

<input type="checkbox"  name="roles_method_id[]"  value="1"   /><span class="Olabel"></span>

</div>

</td>
                                    </tr>
                                 
                                    <tr>
                                     <td>Role2</td><td>
<div class="Oinput" id="Ocheckbox">
<span class="rcs_input_label"></span>


<input type="checkbox" name="roles_method_id[]" value="2" <?php echo set_checkbox('roles_method_id', '2'); ?> 

</div>
                                            
                                            

</td>
                                    </tr>
```

How to get past saved check boxes with same name from database in codeigniter the data is saved but can't populate from database , if there is any way to get it from database using codeigniter or even using ajax to update

Comment: what about your controller and model code for interaction with database.?

Comment: edit your post with controller function